# OSTN02 Transformation

Tags: qgis, qfield

QGIS 3.22.11
I'm trying to add the OSTN02_NTv2.gsb to QGIS.

The Manual says

> 1. Place the NTv2 file (.gsb) in the CRS/Proj folder that QGIS uses (e.g.
>    C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj for windows users)
> 2. Add nadgrids (+nadgrids=nameofthefile.gsb) to the Proj definition in
>    the Parameters field of the Custom Coordinate Reference System
>    Definition (Settings ► Custom Projections…).

I am a WIndows User, but there is no C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj directpry. Instead, should it be C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.11\share\proj.

Also, I do not understand item 2.

What is, and how do I add nadgrids?

Comment: How have you installed QGIS? I guess that you have not used the OSGeo4W installer.

Comment: I installed using the QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.22.11-1.msi file. All default settings, no C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj directory created.

Comment: Maybe the image here https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#integrate-an-ntv2-transformation-in-qgis helps. The directory C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.11\share\proj is probably right for you but you can check if from Settings-Options-System-Current environmental variables. The variable to look for is "PROJ_LIB".

Comment: That's item 1 sorted, thanks.
Sorry, I'm being dim about Item 2. I can get to Custom Coordinate Reference System Definition dialog, but them I'm lost what to do. The image in the manual doesn't get me there. Presumably name is OSTN02? Then what do I put into Parameters.

Comment: I have no idea about what is your projection and what is OSTN02. Maybe you can teach me.

Comment: My Projection is British National grid. EPSG 27700.
OSTN02 is the Ordnance Surveys grid shift Transformation - see https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/tools-support/os-net/format
It is a form of NTv2, a standard binary grod shrift. see The NTv2 (National Transformation version 2) is a standard binary grid shift - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTv2
I get log messages stating I do not have the most accurate transformation available. So I'm trying to address that. It all seems opaque with little detailed guidance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140445/discussion-between-oisin-and-user30184).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the grid shift file into the Proj data directory and use this proj string. The base you can find with `projinfo EPSG:27700` and from the line `PARAMETERFILE["Latitude and longitude difference file","OSTN02_NTv2.gsb"` you can see that the file is found and used.

```
projinfo "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs +type=crs +nadgrids=OSTN02_NTv2.gsb"
PROJ.4 string:
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +nadgrids=OSTN02_NTv2.gsb +units=m +no_defs +type=crs

WKT2:2019 string:
BOUNDCRS[
    SOURCECRS[
        PROJCRS["unknown",
            BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",
                DATUM["Unknown based on Airy 1830 ellipsoid",
                    ELLIPSOID["Airy 1830",6377563.396,299.3249646,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                            ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8901]]],
            CONVERSION["unknown",
                METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
                    ID["EPSG",9807]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",49,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8801]],
                PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-2,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8802]],
                PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996012717,
                    SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8805]],
                PARAMETER["False easting",400000,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8806]],
                PARAMETER["False northing",-100000,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8807]]],
            CS[Cartesian,2],
                AXIS["(E)",east,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                        ID["EPSG",9001]]],
                AXIS["(N)",north,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                        ID["EPSG",9001]]]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
            DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                AXIS["latitude",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["longitude",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            ID["EPSG",4326]]],
    ABRIDGEDTRANSFORMATION["unknown to WGS84",
        METHOD["NTv2",
            ID["EPSG",9615]],
        PARAMETERFILE["Latitude and longitude difference file","OSTN02_NTv2.gsb",
            ID["EPSG",8656]]]]
```

Comment: Absolute start. Many thanks